# Как подключить локальную библиотеку?

Tags: c, linux

Моя программа будет выполнена до запуска операционной системы, поэтому приходится реализовывать некоторые функции стандартных библиотек самому.

Работаю с библиотекой `newt`, которая использует `slang`. 
Как подключить локальную библиотеку `slang`?

Глобальная подключается с помощью -lslang при компиляции в gcc.

Локальная `newt` библиотека имеет файл libnewt.a.
Исходники `slang` не имеют файла библиотеки с расширением *.a.
Подскажите пожалуйста как быть?

Comment: Другими словами, суть вопроса состоит в *как сделать статическую сборку с динамической библиотекой?* Так?

Comment: @avp Библиотека, которая сейчас динамическая, я хочу сделать статической, дабы вносить в нее изменения свои и кое-что дописать, чтобы посмотреть как это будет отражаться на моей программе. Естественно то, что я не могу получить доступ к динамической библиотеке.

Comment: Если дописывать, то естественно, взять сорсы и сваять статическую библиотеку из .o (см. man ar)  / А вот сделать статическую из динамической -- это было бы интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как быть?

например, установить пакет с нужным файлом `libslang.a`.

в debian-основных дистрибутивах пакет называется как-нибудь вроде *libslang2-dev* (ключевой момент тут — суффикс *-dev*).

в redhat-основных дистрибутивах — как-нибудь вроде slang-static (ключевой момент — суффикс *-static*).

Comment: Это самое простое и очевидное решение, но как-то это неинтересно...

Comment: @avp, «вам шашечки или ехать?»